# UknownFunction when calling NewObject on JNI.H

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, unreal-engine4

Ok, so I'm trying to include an embeeded JDK into UnrealEngine to run JavaSE code. The code is feeded dynamically through a text oanel In-game, then written and compiled. When I try to construct a new object from this class, it fails when calling the JNI NewObjec. This is my implementation from c++:

```
FString javacCommand = (javacPath + filePath);

string stringCommand = string(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*javacCommand));

UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("File Created: %s"), *javacCommand);
cout << worked << "\n";

system(stringCommand.c_str());
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Class compiled successfuly"));

try {
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("UserCode");

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Class loaded successfuly"));

    // Get the method that you want to call
    jmethodID createMaterial = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "createJson", "()V");
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CreateMaterial Method loaded Successfully"));

    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "void(V)");
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Constructor Method Loaded Successfuly"));

    jobject object = env->NewObject(clazz, constructor);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Created New Object Sucessfully"));

    // Call the method on the object
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(object, createMaterial);

    jstring resultString = (jstring) result;

    // Get a C-style string
    const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(resultString, NULL);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(resultString, str);

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Class method invoked successfuly with result: %s"), str);
    std::cout << str;
}
```

The java code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.gamifycode.*;
import com.gamifycode.craftableitem.*;
import com.gamifycode.enumeration.State;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UserCode
{


    public UserCode()
    {
    }

    public CraftableItem createCraftableItem() {
    return null;
    }

    public void createJson() throws IOException {
        CraftableItem createdItem = createCraftableItem();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File("JsonFile.json"), createdItem);
    }
}
```

And stacktrace:

```
Signal 11 caught.
Malloc Size=65538 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=65554 
CommonUnixCrashHandler: Signal=11
Malloc Size=65535 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=131119 
Malloc Size=728176 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=859312 
[2020.02.01-02.29.54:237][976]LogCore: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to read memory at address 0x0000000000000000

[2020.02.01-02.29.54:237][976]LogCore: Fatal error!

0x00007fc65569f9bc libjvm.so!JVM_handle_linux_signal(+0x11c)
0x00007fc6556928e8 libjvm.so!UnknownFunction(0x90b8e7)
0x00007fc6ad1f8890 libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x1288f)
0x00007fc655449067 libjvm.so!UnknownFunction(0x6c2066)
0x00007fc65545de5d libjvm.so!UnknownFunction(0x6d6e5c)
0x00007fc65ddf0742 libUE4Editor-CryptydGameJam-9268.so!JNIEnv_::NewObject(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...) [/home/levant/Documents/Repos/Unreal/SlimeCrimeLabs/CryptydGameJam/Source/ThirdParty/jdk1.8.0_211/include/../../jdk1.8.0_211/include/jni.h:872]
0x00007fc65ddefbcb libUE4Editor-CryptydGameJam-9268.so!UCodeInputWidget::compileCode(FText) [/home/levant/Documents/Repos/Unreal/SlimeCrimeLabs/CryptydGameJam/Source/CryptydGameJam/Private/CodeInputWidget.cpp:124]
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: You have the wrong signature for `<init>`. It should be `()V`, not `void(V)`.

Comment: when I try with ()V instead of void(v), it dies right there. I've been doing some debugging, and I think the problem is that the jvmś classpath is not the same place where javac is placeing the .class. Still, the signature indeed was not the right one. ()V is for void